# Accessing Tomcat manager throws 404

Tags: tomcat7, tomcat-manager

I am using Tomcat 7.0.65.

Here is my tomcat-users.xml:

```
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="manager,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-status"/>
```

Here is the server realm snippet in server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

I can access the below urls : [It asks for the credentials for the first time]

http://localhost:8080/manager/status
http://localhost:8080/manager/status/all

But accessing any of the urls :

http://localhost:8080/manager/text/sessions?path=/examples
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/serverinfo

fails with "404 Not found". Below is the displayed error message:

```
The page you tried to access (/manager/text/sessions) does not exist.

The Manager application has been re-structured for Tomcat 7 onwards and some of URLs have changed. All URLs used to access the Manager application should now start with one of the following options:

/manager/html for the HTML GUI
/manager/text for the text interface
/manager/jmxproxy for the JMX proxy
/manager/status for the status pages
Note that the URL for the text interface has changed from "/manager" to "/manager/text".

You probably need to adjust the URL you are using to access the Manager application. However, there is always a chance you have found a bug in the Manager application. If you are sure you have found a bug, and that the bug has not already been reported, please report it to the Apache Tomcat team.
```

Note that I am accessing the url as /manager/text . Even curl fails with the same error.

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, I found the real cause was the ManagerServlet was failing to get instantiated with the below security exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted (ContainerServlet) class org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet
```

The way to fix is to set "privileged=true" in the "Context" section in TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/conf/context.xml

```
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context privileged="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.
```

Comment: is this valid for tomcat 8 also?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the roles below in the conf/tomcat-users.xml file.

```xml
<user username="test" password="test" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

Comment: <user username="test" password="test" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>